# What is the difference between a binding.name.text && name.text if data binding is enabled in both cases

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I just began to learn data binding and I have some troubles in understanding its technique

in my following code, I have enabled data binding in the app Gradle file in order to use it and get rid of the findviewbyid() ... So I've created the binding variable as lateinit before the oncreate() function and then I initialized it in the on create fun like this: `binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)`  and I will give you an example of a view in my XML file to complete on ...

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/nickName_editText"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/Margin"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Back to the kotlin file what is the difference between these two lines of code below (***Both lines are working**)
`nickName_editText.visibility = View.VISIBLE`

`binding.nickNameEditText.visibility = View.VISIBLE`

I know that we want to get rid of the findviewbyid() to make the app faster but why don't we do it like in the first line and we are not calling findViewById() too

I'm new to android development so I might not be able to understand that complicated answers :‑D

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are both forms of data binding, binding.nicknameEditText is Androids implementation, and the recommended approach. "nickName_editText" is Kotlin data binding and has known bug issues, when you get into more complicated views they'll start to pop up.

Expanded your imports in the MainActivity, you'll notice the following import.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

The start indicates binding for all views in the layout.

If you "remove kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*" you'll notice that the "nickName_EditText" is now undefined.

You can also view the Kotlin byte code by

```
clicking on tools/Kotlin/show Kotlin ByteCode
```

If you click on "nickName_editText" you'll notice the bytecode for this section will be highlighted.

Hopefully, this answers all your questions